# Transitive Probability Constraints Take 2

Tags: probability

We know that $P(B|A)$ and $P(C|B)$ don't generally constraint $P(C|A)$. But do $P(B|A)$, $P(\neg A|\neg B)$, $P(C|B)$, $P(\neg B|\neg C)$ jointly constrain $P(C|A)$ and $P(\neg A|\neg C)$? In particular, let $t > \frac{1}{2}$ be such that

$t \leq$ $P(B|A)$, $P(\neg A|\neg B)$, $P(C|B)$, $P(\neg B|\neg C)$.

What does this tell us about $P(C|A)$ and $P(\neg A|\neg C)$? In particular, does it imply $P(C|A)$, $P(\neg A|\neg C)$ $\leq 1 - t$ can't both hold?

Answer (score 1):

(-----Answer to the old question-----)

Consider the probability function $P$ that assigns the following probabilities to atomic events:
$$P(\neg A \wedge B \wedge C) = \frac{2}{3}$$
$$P(A \wedge B \wedge \neg C) = \frac{1}{12}$$
$$P(\neg A \wedge \neg B \wedge C) = \frac{1}{12}$$
$$P(\neg A \wedge \neg B \wedge \neg C) = \frac{1}{6}$$
The other atomic events get null probability by the function $P$.

With such assignment we have that $P(B|A)=1$, $P(C|B)=\frac{8}{9}$, $P(\neg A|\neg B)=1$ and $P(\neg B|\neg C)=\frac{2}{3}$. Note that $P(C|A)=0$ under the distribution $P$. Therefore, the implication you suggest does not hold (take $t=\frac{2}{3}$, for example).

Comment: fantastic, thanks a lot. I now realise that the property i'm after is actually a little different. I want to know whether $t \leq P(C|B), P(\neg B|\neg C), P(B|A), P(\neg A|\neg B)$ guarantees that $P(C|A)$, $P(\neg A|\neg C) \leq 1 - t$ can't both hold.  I'm editing the question to reflect this. My apologies for the mistake.